# Supported default light/dark mode colors for Color vs UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, swiftui

I'm trying to use Apple’s built in colors (`UIColor.label`, `UIColor.secondaryLabel`, etc), but I can't seem to find their `Color` equivalent. Since I can't use them as a `Color`, I can't use them in my SwiftUI code. Is there any way to use these colors in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to modify some code I found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-read-the-red-green-blue-and-alpha-color-components-from-a-uicolor) to make solution. Not the best solution in the world, but it appears to work.

```
extension Color {
    static var label = Color.from(uicolor: .label)

    static func from(uicolor: UIColor) -> Color {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0

        uicolor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        return Color(red: Double(red), green: Double(green), blue: Double(blue)).opacity(Double(alpha))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Text("Test").color(.label)
```